# How can I get sorted results from DynamoDB without Sort Key?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I created a dynamoDB and I did not create a sort Key at the time of creation. I now want to get the results sorted based on a particular attribute of the table. I figured out that the sort key cannot be added to an already existing table.

Is there some other way that I can query the results sorted?

Comment: You can add more indices (a GSI) and include a sort key there.

Comment: Why don't you want to sort after retrieval?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a sort key, your options will be limited to one of the following choices:

1. Create a global secondary index that has a sort key.
2. Perform the sorting operation in your application code.

The second option may give you trouble if your data is paginated.  With a sort key in place, paginated results would be returned in sort order.  If you're doing sorting entirely within your application code, you'd need to account for this.